# Symbolic link creation for html failed to load CSS

Tags: html, css, symlink

I created a symbolic link from a directory to a file (`index.html`).It worked, But the problem is it failed to load the css content which was given as a link to `index.css` in index.html.

How to make it work normal to load the css also?

symbolic link :

> lrwxrwxrwx. 1 username ug2k13cse 13 Oct 28 15:31 index.html -> ../index.html

My code structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Some title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/index.css">
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello world!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please support your question with some code.

Comment: your 'css' folder should be in the parent directory of 'index.html' file. is it there?

Comment: yeah it is in parent directory the link path was correct

Comment: try putting the css folder relative to the symbolic link location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why it is happening**

1. When you create a symbolic link to file, you actually tell the file system that it can reach the file using a new location address.
2. When your browser opens and parse the file, it refers to CSS file according to your symbol link location.

**How to fix**

*Option one*: add the symbol link for your css file in the same location where your HTML file symbol link is.

*Option two*: change the path to your CSS file in your HTML file.

Hope it works for you!

Comment: No creating symbolic link for css file aslo doesn't worked